# Highcharts - Click event not firing outside of plot area

Tags: jquery, svg, highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/jriggs/N6HGK/

To replicate, try clicking the area to the left or right of the legend.

I have also tried using the click event for highcharts-0 and even the body tag but that seems to be masked by the svg

Highcharts code:

```
$(function () {
    // create the chart
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            events: {
                click: function(event) {
                    alert ('x: '+ event.xAxis[0].value +', y: '+
                          event.yAxis[0].value);
                }
            }        
        },
        xAxis: {
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
        }]
    });
});

$('#highcharts-0').click(function() {
alert('outside the box');
});
$(document).click(function() {
alert('body tag');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind it to the `chart.container` instead.
Then you can simple override the event with your function.

```
var originalEvent = chart.container.onclick;
chart.container.onclick = function(e) {
    // do what you want
    originalEvent(e);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/N6HGK/1/)

Comment: This seems to be a step in the right direction with the exception that now click events on the series are captured by 'chart.container.onclick' and don't bubble up to the events click (line 7 in jsfiddle). I need to have both. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @jriggs The chart click is only triggered on the plot area.

Answer (score 1):

The definition for the click function since Highcharts 1.2.0 is :

> Fires when clicking on the plot background. The this keyword refers to
>   the chart object itself. One parameter, event, is passed to the
>   function. This contains common event information based on jQuery or
>   MooTools depending on which library is used as the base for
>   Highcharts.

So you can get the event outside the plot background ...

Reference :http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.click

Unfortunately.

Xavier.

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted w/o leaving an explanation, this seems to be helpful info, thanks-

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a roundabout way, but I found the easiest way for me to do it is to attach a single click event to the chart-container object that highcharts marks. I can't seem to specify its id on chart creation, but it's the first child of the first child of the div you rendered it in. For example, if you had:

```
 var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: someIdForDivFoo,
        },
        ...
```

you would then call this directly after creating the chart:

```
 DivFoo.children[0].children[0].addEventListener("click", function () {
            //your click event logic
        });
```

This seems to pick up all click events: series, plot area, title, axis, labels, legends, etc. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Take look at example which add event click to container but in document ready and chart running DOM structure.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#highcharts-0').click(function(){
    alert('a');
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N6HGK/9/